# Ninject 3 Plugin system

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, plugins, ninject

I am a little new to Ninject so i am having a little trouble working out if this is even possible let alone how to do it.

Basically i want to have a directory with a number of plugin dll's that get loaded at runtime. All the plugins in the dlls will implement 2+ interfaces.  The first interface will be IPlugin and will contain methods to intilalise the plugin and stop it. The rest of the interfaces will be interfaces for features that plugin supplies/implements. When i need something that implements 1 of those interfaces i ask ninject/plugin manager for the instance of all the plugins that implement that feature/interface so i can call them. The other catch is i need as single instance of each plugin to be loaded and returned so if a plugin implements 3 interfaces/features the single instance would be returned when ever i ask for any of those features/interfaces.

Lastly i need this all done dynamically as in with no config xml file or hardcoded mappings. Also if possible i would love to use ninject to populate the constructor properties if possible but if that is too hard i can do that via methods on the IPlugin interface.

I know this is more than a little complicated but i am hoping someone can help me out or at least point me in the right direction. I have looked at most of the other posts on plugin systems but they are based on a common interface.  In my case the common interface is for setup only and the rest of the interfaces are different so none of them seem to match.  Also if possible i didn't want the plugins to reference ninject in any way if possible.

So far i have tried the following and it seems to work so i just need to do some dependencies between plugins now

```
public class PluginManager:IDisposable
{
    IKernel kernel;

    public PluginManager()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind(
               x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                     .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IPlugin>()
                     .BindAllInterfaces()
                     .Configure(c =>c.InSingletonScope()));


    }

    public T GetPluginInstance<T>()
    {
        return kernel.Get<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAllPluginInstances<T>()
    {
        return kernel.GetAll<T>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        kernel.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what your problem is.  If the code you posted works, what do you still need help with?

Comment: it works in loading basic plugins but does not support plugins dependant on other plugins and not making plugins available that don't have all their dependencies meet. I thought about doing it as constructor based DI but i don't think that would work as then they would need to be initialised and configured in a particular order wouldn't they?

Comment: My mistake.  I did not expect that part to just work! I am only new to DI and Ninject and it just keeps surprising me. Wondering how i did things before.

Answer (score 0):

OK i feel a little stupid but the above first try that i edited into my first post works really well and handles inter plugin dependencies in constructors etc. I never realised it would be that easy to do with Ninject so i am posting it here as an answer for others trying to do something similar but does not know Ninject that well.

```
public class PluginManager:IDisposable
{
    IKernel kernel;

    public PluginManager()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind(
               x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                     .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IPlugin>()
                     .BindAllInterfaces()
                     .Configure(c =>c.InSingletonScope()));


    }

    public T GetPluginInstance<T>()
    {
        return kernel.Get<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetPluginInstances<T>()
    {
        return kernel.GetAll<T>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        kernel.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Only issue i hit is if a dependency is not found thing die quite badly so better error handling is prob needed when i work out where to put it.

Comment: fixed that by getting an collection of each dependency though not exactly perfect